# Unable to add soap messge body xml namespace prefix in generated service referance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am creating C# WCF client for Java based webservice that accepts SOAP message.
I created ServiceReference from given WSDL file and using it, it creates below SOAP message body

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <getKey xmlns="http://********">
            <arg0 xmlns="">
            <appName>ABC</appName>
            <uniqueId>1</uniqueId>
        </arg0>
    </getKey>
</s:Body>
```

where as Java webservice except only getKey element only with namespace prefix as below

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ns:getKey xmlns:ns="http://********">
            <arg0 xmlns="">
            <appName>ABC</appName>
            <uniqueId>1</uniqueId>
        </arg0>
    </ns:getKey>
</s:Body>
```

Kindly let me know how can I add this namespace prefix.